# Python library to update PDF metadata

Tags: pdf, python, metadata

I want to update the metadata of pdf files.

My additional requirements:

- Python library
- open source (but not viral licences like GPL)
- Still maintained

The list of outdated libraries:

- http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/ no longer maintained
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PDF Last release was four years ago

Comment: "open source (not GPL)" — Do you mean it need not be GPLed, or it must not be GPLed? Are other copyleft licenses acceptable, or do you need a permissive license?

Comment: @Kodiologist I updated the question (but not viral licences like GPL). Is it clear now, our should I update it again?

Answer (score 1):

I took over the [`pypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) and [`PyPDF2`](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) projects and merged them. `pypdf` is the way to go. We use the BSD license.

We also have [docs about how to write metadata](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/metadata.html)

```
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()

# Add all pages to the writer
for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)

# Add the metadata
writer.add_metadata(
    {
        "/Author": "Martin",
        "/Producer": "Libre Writer",
    }
)

# Save the new PDF to a file
with open("meta-pdf.pdf", "wb") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-python-centric answer:

If your workflow is as follows:

1. On the command line, Interactively try single edit in single metadata field,
2. Apply same editing-command on bunch of  PDF files
3. Apply it routinely by calling a script

then you can call Command-line tool [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) (see [github)](https://github.com/exiftool/exiftool) from Python and set PDF metadata.

More links are given in this Reddit Post from 2022: [Bulk add PDF metadata from the command line](https://www.reddit.com/r/datacurator/comments/wckwn3/bulk_add_pdf_metadata_from_the_command_line/)